# How can I post an answer to a question? This is for those stuck in a login loop and if their chrome browser keeps crashing

Tags: permissions, login, google-chrome

Ok so if you are stuck on a login loop and or your Chrome webbrowser keeps crashing. Try emptying your system disk of data files. I have been reading posts on here for ages and then realised it is because my system disk was full. OK so how to remove data when you are stuck in login loop: Get your instalation disk and use try but don't install. When it boots up you will be able to " sudo chmod 777 (files)" try deleting video files of big audio files. Then when you have cleared about a 1Gig try login again. then keep moving out data files that you dont need on your system disk. This stopped Chrome crashing and login loop for me. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: If you want to answer a question, search for that question. Then answer that question. Don't put the answer inside the question!

Comment: With the exception of certain [protected questions](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/protect-questions), new users are not restricted from posting answers here - see for example [Not enough reputation points to post an answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18775/not-enough-reputation-points-to-post-an-answer)

Comment: `sudo chmod 777 (files)` is always bad advice though ;)

Comment: You can post a question and then answer it yourself -please consider doing that - then your question will show as answered for anyone with the same problem.